# C# list min and max range

Tags: c#, list, linq, c#-4.0, range

I have a list of property object which has a price. I want the list to be within certain price.

For example

Max price: 800000
Min price: 200000

```
results = props.results.Where(x => x.PropertyType.ToLower() != propertytype.ToLower()   && (x.Price >= minPrice && x.Price <= maxPrice)).OrderByDescending(x => Math.Abs(x.Price - price));
```

The code is working fine. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `Better way` means? its with performance or with writing?

Comment: Its just Syntax

Comment: just saw some negative votes. Not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just fine.

If you want to, you could create an extension method for `int` (or whatever data type you use) as:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsBetween(this int value, int min, int max)
    {
        return value >= min && value <= max;
    }
}
```

and call it as

```
integers.Where(x => x.IsBetween(3, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write your query to more sophisticated way like,

```
results = props.results.Where(x => x.PropertyType.ToLower() != propertytype.ToLower())
                       .Where(y => y.Price >= minPrice && y.Price <= maxPrice)
                       .OrderByDescending(z => Math.Abs(z.Price - price));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your range condition looks wrong rather it should be `x.Price >= minPrice && x.Price <= maxPrice` and if you are looking for a syntax like SQL `between` then No, there is no such contruct present